# Daily Horoscope api based on birthdate

Tags: asp.net

I want to put daily horoscope based on user's birthdate in my website

Is there any Asp.net horoscope API which i can integret in my website

Comment: Did you try to search on internet?

Comment: Try this one - http://horoscopes-api.launchaco.com

Answer (score 1):

Its really easy

download  **blockspring package** from  [Here](https://api.blockspring.com/domhofmann/dba3c2ca01c063df9cdf9fc6f0cf93f9#use-in-code)

choose horoscopes you want target `("sign" => "cancer")`

```
<?php

require('blockspring.php');

var_dump(Blockspring::runParsed("dba3c2ca01c063df9cdf9fc6f0cf93f9", array("sign" => "cancer") ))->params;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is daily horoscope API from [yahoo](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=_omfgXdL3BGGadhGdrq02Q).